# JQuery giving different access to tags when using this

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery and have a script that creates a dialog via Ajax using the HREF and TITLE tags of an link.  The problem is, I can easily pull the HREF tag out of "this", but the same doesn't apply at all to the TITLE tag.  In the following example, why does an alert correctly appear with the HREF, but not with the TITLE?

```
<script>
$(function (){
    $('a.ajax').click(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        alert(href);
        var title = this.title;
        alert(title);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<a class="ajax" title="A nice title" href="test.html">Click me!</a>
```

I konw I'm missing something small... I've already tried "var title = $(this).title;" and "var title = $(this).attr('title');" and other similar variations, but none get the title.

Comment: Does the link have a title attribute set? I'm not trying to ask a stupid question, but because [it seems to work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/txFmV/) for me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3ZkH/ --- your code just works, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: This may help explain this vs. $(this) for future reference: [jQuery's this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)

Comment: Wasn't a browser issue... it was an included script that was killing access to the TITLE tag in the end.  The script had a line like this: $('a[title]').tooltip(...);  That line stopped letting me access the TITLE tag on all anchors on the page.  Do you have any idea why a simple line like that could make all TITLE tags inaccessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.title` is perfectly valid.

Also your code is working fine.

Check it here : [JSFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e8NuD/)

Comment: Even though you've noticed everything correctly - I cannot agree it is the answer, since it doesn't solve OP's issue.

Comment: @zerkms saying everything is fine and proving it by jsfiddle is helpful here. because it means OP is trying to solve wrong problem.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the code was working for you.  I tested it on a 100% new page with JQuery loaded in from Google API and it did work fine as well.  It took a bit of searching, but finally I tracked down the issue to this little gem in a "helper" script that was written by another programmer:

    $('a[title]').tooltip(...);

That line seems to clear out access by "this" to ALL title tags on anchors throughout the page.  Guess it'd be nice to know why, but the problem is solved.  Thanks for all of your help!